# PyQt5: Python crashes with SIGSEGV *sometimes* when sending pixmap via a signal from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, python-imaging-library, qpixmap

### Background and Issue

I am trying to process streaming data from a camera. Python keeps crashing with this message though:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

The crash happens **sometimes** while emitting the signal containing an image.

My code, shown below, follows this process:

1. A `QObject` named `CameraThread` is instantiated within the GUI and is run by a `QThread`.
2. `CameraThread` instantiates a class `IngestManager` and gives it to the data source. The data source will call `IngestManager`'s `write()` method repeatedly, providing data.

   - The role of `IngestManager` is to redirect the incoming data to waiting threads. [This is the basis for this approach.](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#rapid-capture-and-processing)
3. The worker threads process the data and sends it back to `IngestManager` via a callback method `frame_callback`
4. `IngestManager` emits the signal. This is where it crashes **sometimes**.

### What I've tried / Observations

I tried several ways to fix it, including passing the `pyqtSignal` to the worker threads themselves. I also reckon that sometimes, the threads finish and emit at the same time, but I'm not sure how to tackle this.

The crash happens much sooner the more I interact with the GUI, such as rapidly pressing a dummy button. It almost never happens if I don't interact with the UI (but it still happens). I think I may need lock of some sorts.

*How do I start solving this problem?*

---

This is the code that connects to the data source, processes the data, and emits the signal.

```
import io
import threading

from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class CameraThread(QObject):
    signal_new_frame = pyqtSignal(QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        with DataSource() as source:
            output = IngestManager(frame_signal=self.signal_new_frame)

            # The source continuously calls IngestManager.write() with new data
            source.set_ingest(output)


class IngestManager(object):
    """Manages incoming data stream from camera."""

    def __init__(self, frame_signal):
        self.frame_signal = frame_signal

        # Construct a pool of 4 image processors along with a lock to control access between threads
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.pool = [ImageProcessor(self) for _ in range(4)]
        self.processor = None  # First "frame" intentionally dropped, else thread would see garbled data at start

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):  # Frame detected
            if self.processor:
                self.processor.event.set()  # Let waiting processor thread know a frame is here

            with self.lock:
                if self.pool:
                    self.processor = self.pool.pop()
                else:
                    # All threads popped and busy. No choice but to skip frame.
                    self.processor = None

        if self.processor:
            self.processor.stream.write(buf)  # Feed frame data to current processor

    def frame_callback(self, image):
        print('Frame processed. Emitting.')
        self.frame_signal.emit(image)


class ImageProcessor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, owner: IngestManager):
        super(ImageProcessor, self).__init__()

        # Data Stuff
        self.stream = io.BytesIO()

        # Thread stuff
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.owner = owner
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.event.wait(1):
                pil_image = Image.open(self.stream)
        
                # Image is processed here, then sent back
                # ...
                # ...
        
                q_image = ImageQt(pil_image)
                q_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(q_image)
        
                self.owner.frame_callback(q_pixmap)

                # Reset the stream and event
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.stream.truncate()
                self.event.clear()
                
                # Return to available pool
                with self.owner.lock:
                    self.owner.pool.append(self)
```

And this is how the code above is used:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from Somewhere import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showFullScreen()

        # Task and thread instantiated. Task is then assigned to thread.
        self._thread = QThread()
        self._cam_prev = CameraThread()
        self._cam_prev.moveToThread(self._thread)

        # Signals are connected.
        self._cam_prev.signal_new_frame.connect(self.update_image)  # UI signal to show image on QLabel
        self._thread.started.connect(self._cam_prev.run)  # Trigger task's run() when thread is ready
        self._thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QPixmap)
    def update_image(self, q_pixmap: QPixmap):
        self.q_cam_preview.setPixmap(q_pixmap)
```

Comment: It's not safe to use QPixmap outside the main thread. Use QImage instead.

Comment: PS: `ImageQt` shares the buffer from the `Image` passed to it. So if the buffer is deleted while the qt image is still alive, a crash will very likely ensue. You might need to [copy the qt image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy) to prevent this happening if you can't keep hold of the pil image for long enough.

Comment: @ekhumoro Creating a copy of the `QImage` seems to have stopped the crashes. I'll let it run for a few more hours and report back. Thanks  for the tip!

Comment: @ekhumoro My software ran for almost 20 hours now without any hitches. I'll be more than happy to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your issue. I've posted an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not safe to use `QPixmap` outside the main thread. So you should use `QImage` instead.

Secondly, `ImageQt` shares the buffer from the `Image` passed to it. So if the buffer is deleted while the Qt image is still alive, a crash will very likely ensue. You might need to [copy the Qt image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy) to prevent this happening if you can't keep hold of the PIL image for long enough.